# Segmentation fault when I try to run Anaconda Navigator

Tags: python, ubuntu, anaconda, navigator

I have recently Installed Anaconda for Python 3.6 but it shows the error "Segmentation fault" whenever I try to run Anaconda-Navigator.
I've tried just writting in the terminal Anaconda-Navigator and also going to my Anaconda3 folder and try to execute it inside bin.

The only solution that works so far is accessing the previously bin folder as root. My problem is that I need to activate TensorFlow before I run anything in my console, but that is imposible as a root user.

I've already try to upgrade both, Anaconda and Navigator and reinstall them but nothing ocurrs

Anyone here has any idea of what is happening?

Comment: This site is for questions about programs you've written, not about third party software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue today, and I solved by running:
`conda upgrade anaconda`

The output said:

```
The following packages will be DOWNGRADED due to dependency conflicts:

anaconda-navigator: 1.5.1-py36_0                                   --> 1.5.0-py36_0
```

after that, I launched anaconda-navigator (no segfault this time) and a window prompted me to upgrade to 1.5.1. I clicked yes, and now running anaconda-navigator 1.5.1 without segfaults on launch. Don't know what is the reason

Answer (score 8):

Had the same problem with my anaconda install. It is probably related to incompatible versions of conda and anaconda navigator.

```
conda update --all
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to install opencv via conda then I got the same error. Later I followed the

```
conda update conda
conda update anaconda-navigator
conda update navigator-updater
```

Then I did

```
conda update --all
```

Voila, its working again

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when I install OpenCV library using conda.Most probably downgrading something makes this issue happen. Just type :
conda update --all

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.I solved it by adding /lib to mt LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Note: On my system Anaconda installation path is /home/pushyamik/anaconda3.